# j2me ContactList.commit() error

Tags: java-me, nokia, jsr75, pim

I have an application which use to write contacts using ContactList.commit(). I am using this app on 2 different mobiles, one is Nokia X2-02 and other Samsung DUOS E2252. 
When I use this code in Samsung DUOS, it goes inside *`if`* statement that means it supports these fields of `Contact.TEL` and `Contact.ATTR_MOBILE`, and probably also executes `c.addString(...)` statement. But when committing using `c.commit()` it throws `PIMException` and simply ignores the whole contact, while using the same application in Nokia phone it works fine. I wonder if Samsung doesn't supports `ATTR_MOBILE` field, it should simply ignore that filed but instead of that it throws exception and ignores the whole contact. What I want to do is simply ignore that particular field if it doesn't add that or whatever rather than ignoring the contact. My code for this portion is below

```
if (clist.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
                if ((clist.isSupportedAttribute(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_HOME)) && (contact.getPhoneHome() != null)) {
                    c.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_HOME, contact.getPhoneHome());
                }
                if ((clist.isSupportedAttribute(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_PAGER)) && (contact.getPager() != null)) {
                    c.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_PAGER, contact.getPager());
                }
                if ((clist.isSupportedAttribute(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_MOBILE)) && (contact.getPhoneMobile() != null)) {
                    c.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_MOBILE, contact.getPhoneMobile());
                }
      }   c.commit();
```

Comment: someone? i'm stuck in this problem too..

Comment: I found it's solution a long time back, and now it works fine...